# is it possible transfer an image via rs-232 serial-port cable?

Tags: serial, rs232

*I want to take an image from a medical device. Should I take the data first and then visualize it in pc via another program?

Comment: Take! .?? Transfer ? Why not?

Comment: Try to avoid "is it possible" questions. I could answer "No, it's not possible." and then someone else comes along and does it anyway. RS232 is just a way to transfer **data**. Is an image data? If it is in digital form it is and can be transferred over RS232. Heck, I could use **smoke signals** to transfer ones and zeros (which is data) and use that to transfer an image. Do you think that would be practical? RS232 is faster than smoke signals but not comparable to any modern data transfer standard. If the image data is large, it will take a while (like hours).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an EE question.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible transfer an image via rs-232 serial-port cable?

Yes, you can transfer pretty much any data over RS-232.  Those of us old enough to remember dial-up modems for internet connection will have downloaded all sorts of data over RS-232.

> Should I take the data first and then visualize it in pc via another program?

I guess so.  It makes sense.  But you haven't suggested any alternatives you are considering.